# Activities Overview not closing with xbindkeys

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnome-3, xdotool

I have a shiny new mouse with which I'm trying to map a keypress to a mouse button.

Specifically, I want a mouseclick to open and close the activities overview in Gnome 3.

When I press the Left Super key, the overview opens. When I press it again, it closes. I have the mouse button mapped to the "Super_L" key using xbindkeys & xdotool, but I can only open the overview with it. It doesn't close when I press the mouse button again. (Unless I hover over one of my open windows, then it closes.)

It's almost like xbindkeys or xdotool is not receiving the click event when the activities overview is active.

Here is my .xbindkeysrc file:

```
"xdotool key Super_L"
release + b:8
```

Comment: Observe this too on Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome 3.30 in Xorg. In `.xbindkeysrc` I tried `xdotool key super`, `xdotool key --clearmodifiers super`, `xdotool key Super_L`, `xdotool key --clearmodifiers Super_L` and in combination with `b:6 + release` or `release + b:6`, but it only opens the activities overview, not closing it afterwards. Interestingly, executing the following in the terminal `xdotool key super ; sleep 3s ; xdotool key super` indeed closes the overview after 3 seconds.

Comment: Also tried `"xte 'key Super_L'"` instead of `"xdotool key super"`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers  Super_L"
    release + b:8
```

Try this code. I always use `--clearmodifiers`   with xbindkeys

Comment: Adding `--clearmodifiers` doesn't work. See my comment above.